# hive top K sum() records per group by key

Tags: hive, window-functions

for a table TBL with columns A, B, C, I want to group by and select A, B where I only take the top K values of B very sum(C)

without the top limit, this is:

```
select A, B, sum(C) from TBL group by A, B
```

with the values

```
A | B | C
--+---+----
a | 1 | 10
a | 2 | 20
a | 1 | 5
a | 3 | 12
b | 3 | 100
b | 2 | 90
b | 1 | 120
c | 5 | 10
```

and limit of 2, the results will be

```
A | B | sum(C)
--+---+-------
a | 1 | 15
a | 2 | 20
b | 1 | 120
b | 3 | 100
c | 5 | 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      A
           ,B
           ,sum_C

from       (select      A
                       ,B
                       ,sum(C) as sum_C

                       ,row_number () over
                        (
                            partition by    A
                            order by        sum(C) desc
                        ) as rn

            from        TBL 

            group by    A
                       ,B
            ) t

where       rn <= 2
```

---

```
+---+---+-------+
| a | b | sum_c |
+---+---+-------+
| a | 2 |    20 |
| a | 1 |    15 |
| b | 1 |   120 |
| b | 3 |   100 |
| c | 5 |    10 |
+---+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) to achieve this.

**Query**:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY c DESC) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT A   AS a
      , B      AS b
      , SUM(C) AS c
    FROM db.table
    GROUP BY A, B ) x ) y
WHERE rank < 3
```

**Output**:

```
a       b       c
a       2       20
a       1       15
b       1       120
b       3       100
c       5       10
```

Comment: No need for 3 levels of sub-queries.